# Free resources from inactive $mdTab

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular web application that has date pickers under multiple $mdTabs. Because the date picker I'm using treats each day as an object, if I have more than 2 tabs on a page, I experience significant performance issues.

Is there a way to only load resources when a tab is active?

Comment: I'm currently considering writing a new directive with isolate scope, and putting that in the `<md-tab-body>` section of my html, then loading the pertinent information only when the tab is selected.